# I have both var and var1 folders in my directory - which one to use? (Magento 2.1)

Tags: magento-2.1

I have both var and var1 folders in my Magento 2 directory.
I've no idea why, but I need to remove one of them due to space.
Could anyone help me understand why the second one appears, and which one do I remove?

Comment: someone other than you may have rename your var folder to var1. If var folder not found magento will recreate that folder again.Just take a backup and then  remove var1 folder.

Comment: You must care about Var folder and Var1 is nothing just created by someone manually.

Answer (score 1):

Magento does a lot of caching and autogeneration of certain class types. These caches and generated classes are all located in Magento's root var directory. The usual contents of the var directory is as follows:

- cache
- composer_home
- generation
- log
- tmp
- view_preprocessed
- importexport
- page_cache

So maybe someone backup directory(var1). You can delete var1 directory